# What breed is Deckard's dog in Blade Runner 2049

Tags: animals, blade-runner-series, actor-identification, blade-runner-2049

In Blade Runner 2049, what is the breed of the dog that Deckard owns?

I've checked the IMDB credits and neither dog (not massively surprising), nor trainer is listed.

[image: Here's the back of the dog, for comparisons]

Comment: Whatever breed you call a robot dog.

Comment: Do robotic dogs dream of electric rabbits?

Comment: Canoid?  Candroid?

Comment: I regret there isn't a stack overflow for puns.

Comment: Obviously, he's a Botweiler

Comment: @thomasmichaelwallace there's one for riddles; time to demand one for puns

Comment: I don't know. Why don't you ask him?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like an Estrela Mountain Dog to me.

Elkhound is not even a close comparison.

[image: Estrela Mountain Dog]

Comment: Can you elaborate and perhaps provide either a source or photographic comparisons? This would help to improve this answer greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Norwegian Elkhound. He is pretty big for that breed, so might be a mix.

Comment: This answer would be improved by side by side pictures of Deckard's dog and a Norwegian Elkhound, or some source stating that that is the breed of the dog.

Answer (score 1):

The dog is a Caucasian Ovcharka, probably a small female.

Comment: This answer would be improved by side by side pictures of Deckard's dog and a Caucasian Ovcharka, or some source stating that that is the breed of the dog.

Comment: While your answer may well be correct (I know nothing about dogs), we need answers to provide evidence rather than just an assertion. Perhaps an official description of the breed, and a list of the points of similarity.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was a sharplaninatz. They would have just shaved her a bit. I used to have one a long time ago. Such wonderful dogs. I miss her.

Comment: Can you provide so evidence to back up your assertion?